# gnuplot: compact axis label format

Tags: format, label, gnuplot, axis, exponential

Tell me how in gnuplot to properly form the inscriptions in the axis (as shown in the picture).

1) I do not know the values of the y axis

2) I need to set the exponent (power 10) in the axis label automatically

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the order of magnitude of your data before plotting. If you don't know it beforehand, you can get this via `stats` (check `help stats`). Then divide your y-values by a factor which (in the example below) is chosen such that the y-axis tics should show values with two digits (`digits=2`), i.e. range 0-100.

**Script:**

```
### automatic prefactor in axis scaling and axis label
reset session

# generate some random data
p  = floor(rand(0)*20-10)
y0 = rand(0)
set samples 20
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 0:(y0*10**p/($0)) with table
unset table

# get the maximum via stats
stats $Data u 2 nooutput
yMax = STATS_max

digits    = 2
factorLog = ceil(log10(yMax)) - digits
factor    = 10**factorLog

set ylabel sprintf("y-title, x 10^{%d} units", factorLog) font ",12"
set format y "%g"
set boxwidth 0.7 relative

plot $Data u 1:($2/factor) with boxes fs solid 1.0 fc rgb "red" ti sprintf("Max value %.2e", yMax)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]